# Dotnet tool restore AggregateException

Tags: .net, sdk

My project doesn't want to start as it cannot find the SDK. The strange thing is that this folder doesn't exist:
[the folder its trying to look into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2E2f.png)

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk path exist and that path contains the SDKs version... not the folder. However I tried doing a Dotnet tool restore  altough I get this exception:
[AggregateException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BELgD.png)

Installing and reinstalling the SDKs and visual studio, also a repair